# Suddently I started getting this error on my SugarCRM instance."Getting Error “Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.”

Tags: php, azure, sugarcrm

My SugarCRM is hosted at Microsoft Azure, suddenly I am getting this message:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

A reboot does solve a problem, but I want to fix the core issue.

Please suggest. Reboot is fixing issue.

Comment: SugarCRM version? have you checked SugarCRM and apache logs?

Comment: it's SugarCE 6.5.24, Nothing in error logs like SugarCRM and apache logs. Just rebooting is fixing issue.